# can't use DEBUG flag in visual studio code for tests

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, xunit

I have a unit test setup in visual studio code where i need to read a test data file, load it into an HtmlDocument (HtmlAgilityPack) and test a Parser class. At the top of the class I have

```
public class MegaParserTests{

private HtmlDocument _hd;
private MegaParser _parserUT;

public ParserTests() {
    _parserUI = new MegaParser();
    _hd = new HtmlDocument()

#if DEBUG
    filePath = "data/theDoc.html";
#else
    filePath = @"../../../data/theDoc.html";
#endif

    var docStr = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    _hd.LoadHtml(doc);
}
}
```

I have used the #if DEBUG as the file path seems to change depending on whether I "debug test" or do a "dotnet test" from the command line. However when I do a dotnet test, the top "#if DEBUG" condition is hit and I get the wrong filepath. Why is it when I run dotnet test the runtime thinks I'm in debug mode.. and how can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually `dotnet test` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-test) uses the `Release` build configuration by default... Try to use `-configuration` flag to force Release build configuration:

```
dotnet test -c Release
```

> -c|--configuration
>
> Configuration under which to build. The default value is Release.